# OSX - Disable keychain password prompts

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

How do I disable the OSX keychain password prompt? This machine is our local build server (running hudson). Everytime the automated build script runs code signing, the keychain pw prompt pops up and halts everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Always allow* access to that keychain item when asked.

---

Open /Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access and make sure that the keychain containing the relevant item(s) is unlocked, and will not lock automatically by selecting *Edit, Change Settings for Keychain...*.

Comment: Thanks! side note: Edit->Change Settings for "System" Keychain is always greyed up (even when unlocked). To change the settings for the System keychain, you need to Right click on keychain -> click "Change Settings for Keychain "System", then Disable Inactivity & Sleep Lock.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the "Lock after X minutes of inactivity" setting with the following command:

```
security set-keychain-settings ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Note that if Keychain Access is open when you run this command, you'll need to close it and reopen to see the change in the keychain settings dialog.