# osx - Set application access to certificate via command line

Tags: ssh, osx-lion, terminal.app, keychain-access

I want to allow permanent access to certificates for certain app (eg codesign) via command line. The gui equivalent would be clicking "Always Allow" when prompted. However I only have access via SSH

I want to do what is asked in this question: [OSX - Disable keychain password prompts](https://superuser.com/questions/276496/osx-disable-keychain-password-prompts) only via terminal.

Comment: … does `security add-trusted-cert` help you?

Comment: I dont think so. I want to allow access for certain applications for certificates that already exist

Comment: I don't know a lot about the security options, but `security` is the interface to anything related about it on OS X, so see `man security` for more info.